# A PhD thesis without any publication

Tags: postdocs, early-career

I am currently a Ph.D student(computational maths) works in a theory. I will be graduating in the next year. I have one paper which I will be submitting soon and working one more paper. One of my research article has been published but not related to Ph.D thesis. My first research paper is fully reviewed by my advisor several times. I don't know I will be able to publish anything more in my Ph.D as this is my second last year. I have put of lot of effort in my Ph.D my supervisor also have admit this thing, but verbally. I don't want to do go for a faculty job after my Ph.D, I will be going searching a post-doc after my Ph.D. I am worried about whether I will get a post-doc or not. According to institution norm's there is no requirement of publication in Ph.D.

**Question :** Is it going to harm my research carrier if I submit my  PhD thesis without any publication?

Comment: Which field is this? Are you planning to publish your PhD thesis as a book? Or parts of it as articles, after graduation?

Comment: Have you discussed this with your advisor? If so, what did she/he say? If not, why not?

Comment: I disagree that this was closed. It seems to me to be perfectly suited to this site and useful to future visitors. The question is objective and readers here probably have experience to offer guidance.

Comment: @Buffy You can vote to reopen. I did. My impression is that sometimes questions are closed prematurely by people who can't imagine a generally applicable answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This sort of thing varies by field. In some, there is no expectation at all of publications prior to finishing the degree. I think the push toward requiring publications is somewhat recent. When I finished (long ago) in mathematics it would be very rare to have any publications at all upon graduation.

But in some fields there is such an expectation. However, I think that in those fields, students are funded more for research (RA) than for teaching (TA). If you are part of an active research lab in the sciences it is more natural to have several publications as a consequence of your work prior to graduation.

But any effect at all on your career would likely be very brief. You establish your own reputation. Starting a bit late with publications eventually evens out if you are productive, either in academia or elsewhere.

Of course, it won't harm you to be thinking about what you could get out there in your time remaining. Your advisor should be able to tell you about norms in your field, of course.